# Rspec mocking an error that .backtrace is called on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I am trying to mock an error message for a method that takes an error as an argument and calls .backtrace on it.  my method looks like :

```
 def log_error(error)
    puts error.backtrace
    puts "RECONCILE_TAX_RATES [#{Time.now}] ERROR [#{error.message}]"
  end
```

my test before putting the error.backtrace line in looked like:

```
it 'logs errors' do
    time = "Tue, 16 Sep 2014 20:18:19 UTC +00:00"
    Timecop.freeze(time) do
      tax_reconciler = TaxReconciler.new
      error_message = "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."
      expected = "RECONCILE_TAX_RATES [2014-09-16 20:18:19 UTC] ERROR [I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.]"

      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with(expected)
      tax_reconciler.log_error(error_message)
    end
  end
```

now that the method has changed to take an error and not just a message I am confused as to how to write the test.  Any help is appreciated and let me know if I need to include more info please.

```
the error I am getting is:
 Failure/Error: tax_reconciler.log_error(error_message)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `backtrace' for "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.":String
```

so as per the suggestion below I tried

```
it 'logs errors' do
    time = "Tue, 16 Sep 2014 20:18:19 UTC +00:00"
    Timecop.freeze(time) do
      expected = "RECONCILE_TAX_RATES [2014-09-16 20:18:19 UTC] ERROR [I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.]"
      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with(expected)
      tax_reconciler = TaxReconciler.new
      begin
        raise "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."
      rescue => error_message
        tax_reconciler.log_error(error_message)
      end
    end
  end
```

Ok so the solution as suggested below was as follows:

```
 it 'logs errors' do
    time = "Tue, 16 Sep 2014 20:18:19 UTC +00:00"
    Timecop.freeze(time) do
      expected = "RECONCILE_TAX_RATES [2014-09-16 20:18:19 UTC] ERROR [I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.]"
      tax_reconciler = TaxReconciler.new
      begin
        raise "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."
      rescue => error_message
        STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with(expected)
        STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with(error_message.backtrace)
        tax_reconciler.log_error(error_message)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: What output are you receiving from rspec on that assertion ?

Comment: @Discorick I updated with my current error message. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Rspec Error message, your source of failure is simple. On your spec you are passing in a string as error.

```
error_message = "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."
```

The log_error method is attempting to call 'backtrace" on a string, not an actual exception. 
Try this:

```
begin
  raise "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."
rescue => error_message
  tax_reconciler.log_error(error_message) 
end
```

This will pass an actual exception object into your method.